# UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification returns wrong orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uideviceorientation

I have a `UIScrollView` with sub-views whose frames I have to update on orientation change. I have been running the program on an `iPhone` simulator but it looks like the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` does not return the correct orientation of the device. It returns `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` when I rotate to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft/Right` and vice versa. Am I not using it right or do I have to use some other method of handling orientation change?

Comment: Note that on iOS 7, the iPhone does not support UIInterfaceOrientationPortaitUpsideDown.  That can cause some confusion when rotating the simulator as there's no easy way to distinguish between the two states on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIInterfaceOrientation` != `UIDeviceOrientation`. `UIInterfaceOrientation` is declared as ...

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

... portrait contains same values / numbers, but landscape variants are swapped, etc. You didn't show your code, so, I can just assume, that you're mixing these two things together.

Is there any reason why you're not using `willRotateTo...`, `willAnimateRotation...`, `didRotateFrom...` methods of `UIViewController`?

Comment: Thanks. This helped me out. I had indeed confused the two.